# Case Insensitive Dictionary with Tuple Key

Tags: c#, dictionary, string-comparison

I have a dictionary where the key is a Tuple where the first item is a Date and the second item is a string. I would like the dictionary to be case insensitive.

I know that if the key was just a string I could pass StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase as a parameter when declaring the dictionary, but this does not seem to work when the key is a Tuple.

Is there some way to specify the StringComparer to use on the second item of the Tuple?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) of the `Dictionary` constructor, which allows you to specify a custom comparer for the keys. You would accompany this with creating a class that implements

```
IEqualityComparer<Tuple<string, DateTime>>
```

Which might look like this:

```
class CustomEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<string, DateTime>>
{

    public bool Equals(Tuple<string, DateTime> lhs, Tuple<string, DateTime> rhs)
    {
        return
          StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(lhs.Item1, rhs.Item1)
       && lhs.Item2 == rhs.Item2;
    }


    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<string, DateTime> tuple)
    {
        return StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(tuple.Item1)
             ^ tuple.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

There are no argument checks here, so please don't treat this as production code. Also, care needs to be taken so that the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations satisfy the all-important condition that *if two tuples compare equal, they must have the same hash code*. When dealing with custom text comparisons it is easy to introduce bugs if not extra careful: for example, using `ToLowerInvariant` instead of `ToLower` above would be a bug (albeit one that might not surface for some time).

Comment: Using the same StringComparer to check for equality and for getting the hash code usually works best to avoid the bugs you mention. I've edited the answer with a proposed fix; please undo if you don't like it.

Comment: @dtb: Definitely won't be undoing as this is a consistency improvement also IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I needed this in a `Dictionary<Tuple<>>` wrapper, so I used @Jon 's code to create a generic version

```
public class TupleEqualityComparer<T1, T2> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T1, T2>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T1> comparer1;
    private IEqualityComparer<T2> comparer2;

    public TupleEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T1> comparer1, IEqualityComparer<T2> comparer2)
    {
        this.comparer1 = comparer1 ?? EqualityComparer<T1>.Default;
        this.comparer2 = comparer2 ?? EqualityComparer<T2>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals(Tuple<T1, T2> lhs, Tuple<T1, T2> rhs)
    {
        return comparer1.Equals(lhs.Item1, rhs.Item1) && comparer2.Equals(lhs.Item2, rhs.Item2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<T1, T2> tuple)
    {
        return comparer1.GetHashCode(tuple.Item1) ^ comparer2.GetHashCode(tuple.Item2);
    }

}

public class Dictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue> : Dictionary<Tuple<TKey1, TKey2>, TValue>()
{
    public Dictionary() : base() { }
    public Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey1> comparer1, IEqualityComparer<TKey2> comparer2) : base(new TupleEqualityComparer<TKey1, Tkey2>(comparer1, comparer2) { }

    public TValue this[TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2]
    {
        get { return base[Tuple.Create(key1, key2)]; }
    }

    public void Add(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TValue value)
    {
        base.Add(Tuple.Create(key1, key2), value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2)
    {
        return base.ContainsKey(Tuple.Create(key1, key2));
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, out TValue value)
    {
        return base.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(key1, key2), out value);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, DateTime, int>(
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase, null);
dict.Add("value1", DateTime.Now, 123);
Assert.IsTrue(dict.ContainsKey("VALUe1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the comparisons are going to be case-insensitive, you could use the `toLower`/`toUpper` method in the string side when making the tuples, and then always lower or upper the strings you'll have in the tuples used to retrive/compare entries in the dictionary.

Comment: Comparing strings by converting them to upper or lower case doesn't work properly in some cultures. It's better to use a StringComparer such as StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase