# How can I create a generic case-insensitive multi-key dictionary using ValueTuples?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, case-insensitive, valuetuple

I know that I can define a dictionary with a [System.ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1) key (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831241/1174581)) as below:

```
var multiKeyDictionary = new Dictionary<(int key1, string key2), object>()
{
    {(1, "test"), new object() }
};
```

However, I want any `string` values present in the `ValueTuple` to be treated as case-insensitive using `IEqualityComparer` or something similarly idiomatic for dictionary access, similar to what is [prescribed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230450/1174581).

The solutions I have thought of so far are to:

- [Implement IEqualityComparer like was necessary for `System.Tuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16428534/1174581)
- Wrap all access to the dictionary as below:

```
class InsensitiveValueTupleDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<(int key1, string key2), object> _multiKeyDictionary = new Dictionary<(int key1, string key2), object>();

    public void Add((int key1, string key2) key, object value)
    {
        _multiKeyDictionary.Add((key.key1, key.key2.ToLower()), value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey((int key1, string key2) key)
    {
        return _multiKeyDictionary.ContainsKey((key.key1, key.key2.ToLower()));
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

Both of these strategies will require setup code for every unique combination of `ValueTuple` e.g., `(int, string)`, `(string, int)`, `(string, string, int)`, and so on.

Is there another method that will allow case-insensitive key equality for arbitrary `ValueTuple` combinations?

Comment: That may be my only option, but I was trying to avoid having to implement IEqualityComparer so that I can use without having to create a new version for every potential overload (`(int, string)`, `(string, int)`, `(string, string, int)`, etc). Looking for any alternatives to that approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're painting yourself into that corner by using a tuple. Tuples are meant to represent a bag of values, not an entity.

You can implement your own key type in a tuple friendly way:

```
public struct Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    private readonly int hashCode;

    public Key(int key1, string key2)
    {
        this.Key1 = key1;
        this.Key2 = key2;
        this.hashCode = HashCode.Combine(key1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Key2));
    }

    public int Key1 { get; }
    public string Key2 { get; }

    public bool Equals(Key other)
        => this.hashCode == other.hashCode
            && this.Key1 == other.Key1
            && string.Equals(this.Key2, other.Key2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
        => obj is Key key && this.Equals(key);

    public override int GetHashCode() => this.hashCode;
    
    public static implicit operator (int key1, string key2)(Key key)
        => (key1: key.Key1, key2: key.Key2);
    
    public static implicit operator Key((int key1, string key2) key)
        => new Key(key.key1, key.key2);
    
    public void Deconstruct(out int key1, out string key2)
        => (key1, key2) = (this.Key1, this.Key2);
}
```

You can even use it with tuples or "like" tuples:

```
var key = new Key(1, "one");
var (k1, k2) = key;
(int key1, string key2) t = key;
t.key1 = 2;
t.key2 = "two";
key = t;
```

If you really want to stay with tuples, define your own comparer:

```
public class MyTupleComparer : IEqualityComparer<(int key1, string key2)>
{
    public bool Equals((int key1, string key2) x, (int key1, string key2) y)
        => x.key1 == y.key1
            && string.Equals(x.key2, y.key2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public int GetHashCode((int key1, string key2) obj)
    => HashCode.Combine(obj.key1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.key2));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, I also made the Key struct readonly for added performance.